# How to install Konqueror (standalone) without a bunch of other KDE packages included? via pacman

Tags: pacman-package-manager

I am trying to install Konqueror on my MATE desktop for its smb:// feature. However, when I try to install it from the AUR I am provided with 350MB of extra packages. The package I am trying to install is called kdebase-konqueror, because konqueror by itself doesn't seem to exist.

I would love to know a way to install the browser itself without any other unnecessary dependencies... thank you. Perhaps there isn't a way by pacman, but maybe via another package installer of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

This may be futile.

Look at this here:

ldd konqueror

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffb12d0000)
    libkdeinit4_konqueror.so => /usr/lib64/libkdeinit4_konqueror.so (0x00007f673529d000)
    libkonquerorprivate.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libkonquerorprivate.so.4 (0x00007f6735080000)
    libkonq.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libkonq.so.5 (0x00007f6734e48000)
    libkparts.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libkparts.so.4 (0x00007f6734bf2000)
    libkcmutils.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libkcmutils.so.4 (0x00007f67349b1000)
    libkfile.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libkfile.so.4 (0x00007f6734705000)
    libkio.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libkio.so.5 (0x00007f673424c000)
    libnepomukutils.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libnepomukutils.so.4 (0x00007f673400f000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib64/qt/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f6733cc0000)
    libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib64/qt/lib/libQtXml.so.4 (0x00007f6733a7d000)
    libnepomuk.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libnepomuk.so.4 (0x00007f67337a6000)
    libsoprano.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libsoprano.so.4 (0x00007f67334be000)
    libkdeui.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libkdeui.so.5 (0x00007f6732e4a000)
    libQtSvg.so.4 => /usr/lib64/qt/lib/libQtSvg.so.4 (0x00007f6732bf1000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib64/qt/lib/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f6731f03000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f6731cfc000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f6731ae0000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f67317a6000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f6731595000)
    libXft.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libXft.so.2 (0x00007f673137f000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f673117c000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f6730f77000)
    libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4 (0x00007f6730d65000)
    libkactivities.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libkactivities.so.6 (0x00007f6730b49000)
    libkdecore.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libkdecore.so.5 (0x00007f6730676000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib64/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f6730181000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f672ff64000)
    libQtDBus.so.4 => /usr/lib64/qt/lib/libQtDBus.so.4 (0x00007f672fce3000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f672f9e0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f672f6de000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f672f4c8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f672f0fe000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f672eee9000)
    libsolid.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libsolid.so.4 (0x00007f672ebf5000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f672e9ec000)
    libnepomukquery.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libnepomukquery.so.4 (0x00007f672e7a3000)
    libstreamanalyzer.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libstreamanalyzer.so.0 (0x00007f672e521000)
    libstreams.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libstreams.so.0 (0x00007f672e2e8000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f672e0df000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f672dedb000)
    libsopranoclient.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libsopranoclient.so.1 (0x00007f672dc90000)
    libqca.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libqca.so.2 (0x00007f672d97d000)
    libattica.so.0.4 => /usr/lib64/libattica.so.0.4 (0x00007f672d6ae000)
    libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 (0x00007f672d47a000)
    libXtst.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXtst.so.6 (0x00007f672d275000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f672d06b000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f672ce65000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f672cc64000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f672c90c000)
    libpng14.so.14 => /usr/lib64/libpng14.so.14 (0x00007f672c6e7000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f672c420000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f672c1c9000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f672bf82000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f672bd7f000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f672bb60000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f672b95c000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f672b733000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f672b522000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f672b300000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f672b0e5000)
    libfam.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libfam.so.0 (0x00007f672aedd000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f672acd5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f67355b6000)
    libudev.so.0 => /lib64/libudev.so.0 (0x00007f672aac7000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f672a762000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f672a552000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/../lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f672a345000)
```

You will need a lot of libraries, including some of the kde-specific ones,
such as libkdecore.so and libkdeui.so